# HttpClient login to WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms, asp.net-web-api

I just want to login in Webapi with Authorization using my desktopapp with httpclient then 
i want to access the method inside it.

```
    static async Task RunAsync()
    {

        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential( "helloadmi2n@yahoo.com", "Password.1");

        var client = new HttpClient(handler);

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5088/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));



        var response = await client.GetAsync("api/product/1");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Product product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}\t{2}", product.Name, product.Price, product.Category);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Internal server error");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

in that example I want to log in the call the product controller that is with authorization.

Here is my code in webAPI

```
 [Authorize]
 public class ProductController : ApiController
    {
        Product[] products = new Product[] 
        { 
            new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 }, 
            new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M }, 
            new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M } 
        };


        public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
        {
            var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(product);
        }
    }


  [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("Register")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return GetErrorResult(result);
            }

            return Ok();
        }
```

my response.IsSucessStatusCode always return unauthorized

Comment: What type of authorization is being used? Basic? OAuth? ASP.NET Identity? Windows Integrated? Asp.net Membership?

Comment: WebAPI template project implements CookieAuthentication. I belive that your project also implements the same way, so you need to work with Request/Response headers to get or set cookies.

Comment: I just use basic ASP.net MVC Identity. Can some one gave me at least link for how to solve this?